# Menu submenu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image: This is what i want to create in wordpress.]

This is what i want to create in wordpress. I can create simple menu sub menu but not this type of structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi put your html current demo using jsfiddle or site link. your sub menu structure change mostly css based

Answer (score 0):

if your're using WordPress's default templates, as i know this is not possible, but you can use other themes or templates for your site and check if they have this capability, or maybe you can find a plugin to do that for you and override this function your actual template,
i wish i could help.